# Error during installation of GDAL with ogr2ogr

Tags: linux, dictionary, gdal

Here,i am trying to draw the map of my country and for that i got a article http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/ and the i have installed all the tools said here like as i am user of ubuntu 14.04 , homebrew for linux that is linuxbrew and then through linuxbrew ,i installed the (geospatial Data Abstraction Library)gdal as here said that the gdal install the ogr2ogr.but when checked it with

> > which ogr2ogr , then i did not respond to anything.
> >     then , i tried ..
> >
> > locate ogr2ogr ,then i also did not respond to anything.
> >     but before the installation complete the error message was as follows..

==> make check
make[2]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/libspatialite20150624-14363-fi3prm/libspatialite-4.2.0/test'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/tmp/libspatialite20150624-14363-fi3prm/libspatialite-4.2.0/test'
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1

your help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ogr2ogr` is a tool from GDAL, which is available as a package for Ubuntu ([here is the package metadata](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gdal-bin&searchon=names&section=all)).

As root, install it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

which should install the GDAL tools and all of the dependencies required.